# How to force the ath10k driver choose the firmware API 6 so that I can enable raw_mode on QCA6174 wifi card?

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros, mesh

I work on a computer backed by Ubuntu 16.04, RT preempted kernel 4.16 and latest the linux firmware 1.175.3. My goal is to enable raw mode in QCA6174 chipset based wifi card so that I can create a mesh point. After some research I found out only these firmwares support raw_mode.

https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1.c3
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1.c2

But I don't understand the ath drivers deep enough to automatically choose the right firmware.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search on installing wifi driver and auto compiling with DKMS automatically for every installed kernels version.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find your card's exact model and hw version, I suggest checking dmesg output:

> ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: qca6174 hw**3.2** target 0x05030000 chip_id
>   0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535

After that, you can find the right firmware card on the [linux wireless page for ath10k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/firmware), they are already compiled, just pick the right one based on the card model (including hw version) and your kernel.

Installation instructions are on the [same page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/firmware#update_firmware) too:

> First download the firmware image from the links above. In this
>   example we use firmware-2.bin_10.1.467.2-1 from QCA988X 10.1
>   directory. Then just copy that file as firmware-2.bin to the ath10k
>   firmware directory:
>
> cp firmware-2.bin_10.1.467.2-1
>   /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
>
> Then reload ath10k (or restart the system) and you can check if the
>   new firmware is in use.
>
> Note: In some distributions the firmware location can be different
>   than /lib/firmware.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy updated board-2.bin and firmware-6.bin to /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0 (renaming them) from

https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1.c3/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00059

```
cp ath10k-firmware/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1.c3/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00059 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
```

And then check if correct firmware was used on boot - here is my output after updating firmware

```
[   32.529665] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1028:0410
[   32.529668] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   32.530093] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00059 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad,raw-mode,mfp crc32 3c85e1f9
[   32.776709] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 c15a244d
[   32.844046] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   32.862171] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.62 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another catch. NetworkManager shows WiFi as disabled, when you check it's state with /n

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

and it shows it is hardblocked - means it is disabled by button, but when trying to enable it, it shows that laptop goes to the "Airplane mode"

```
sudo rfkill list all /n
```

will show it is soft blocked but not hardblocked any more  so it is possible to remove softlock

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

voila! All works now.
They messed up physical button state with software state.... normaly if it is hardlocked I would expect Laptop being in Airplane mode... opposite synchronisation in NetworkManager..